# How can I change the CheckChanged when clicking the same object in VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I want to know if it is possible in VB 2010 to changed the `CheckChanged` of a CheckBox when clicking the same object. For Example:

I have a 1 picturebox named `pic1` and a checkbox named `chck1`, If I click the `pic1`, the `chck1` must be checked but If I click again the `pic1`, `chck1` must be unchecked and I click again the `pic1`, `chck1` must be check again and so on..

I really don't have an idea if it is working or impossible in VB 2010, I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mr. Steve, it's Winforms, sorry I forgot to include it on my question.

Comment: What do you think the user is going to click on?  A checkbox says "click on me", a picture says "look at me".  A user that discovers by accident that clicking the picture works is going to be completely flabbergasted.  Creating a sane UI solves many programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a WinForm, then you just have to implement something like this:

you have your PictureBox and your Checkbox, and you just have to add a clickhandler to your picturebox like this:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
    }
```

This Method always negates the Checked-State of the Checkbox (it's way simpler than a if/else)

checkbox1.Checked contains the checked-state, so that is how you can uncheck/check it.

***Edit:*** i did it in c#, sorry,

in VB.NET it would be something like

```
    Private Sub pictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        checkBox1.Checked = Not checkBox1.Checked;
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i just added the VB implementation :D

Answer (score 1):

In a WinForms application just add the event handler for the click event of your PictureBox.
You could that easily with the Form Designer or, if using code, then write

```
' In the form constructor
Public Sub Form1()
    ' First initialize your form controls'
    InitializeComponent()
    ' then add the event handler for the picturebox click event'
    AddHandler pic1.Click, AddressOf pic1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub pic1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' toogle the checked state of the checkbox'
    chk1.Checked = Not chk1.Checked

End Sub
```

As said below from [Mr Neolisk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897326/neolisk) you could also shorten this code simply adding the [Handles clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) to the `pic1_Click` event thus removing the code in the Form constructor

```
Private Sub pic1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pic1.Click

    ' toogle the checked state of the checkbox'
    chk1.Checked = Not chk1.Checked

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it a hybrid of C# and VB.NET? :)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Steve, I will try it in my program.

Comment: Curly braces is C#, VB.NET's syntax is `Sub` ... `End Sub`.

Comment: Ok now, you can also rewrite with handles clause (but that's optional of course - just fewer lines of code). +1

Comment: @Neolisk Working on a C # project and occasionally look SO it is tricky thanks

Comment: I see. Anyway, this is what I meant: `Private Sub pic1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pic1.Click`, then you don't need Sub Form1 at all, which btw should've been `Sub New()` (just noticed now).

Comment: @Neolisk You are right, not my preferred way but... I will add your observation